# Unexpected token , - asp value showing as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

i am trying to upload some data from vb.net to asp.net using array json.

my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {

       var a = $("#hidden").val();
       var array = JSON.parse(a);
```

however, when i debugged this on the browser, "a" and "array" was showing as undefined. even though in the code behind it was showing the value..

after further investigation, i found out that if it is like this it works:

```
  var a = "[1, 2, 3]";
  var array = JSON.parse(a);
```

note it is showing as a string, however when i take the string of:

```
  var a = [1, 2, 3];
  var array = JSON.parse(a);
```

it says its undefined - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token, am guessing its to do with the JSON.

now back to my code and my error:
code behind (vb)

```
    Dim array As New ArrayList

    For Each row In ChartData.Rows
        array.Add(row("Day"))
    Next row

    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim arrayJson As String = serializer.Serialize(array)

    hidden.Value = arrayJson
```

and code in asp.

```
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" runat="server" />         
    var a = $("#hidden").val();
       var array = JSON.parse(a);
```

my problem is, why is it showing undefined! what have i done wrong.

thanks

Comment: You do realise that `#hidden` won't actually be the ID when ASP.NET renders the control? It will look something like `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Hidden`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on asp.net the rendered id is not the one you use on code behind, to get it on page you need to use the `ClientID` as:

```
var a = $("#<%=hidden.ClientID%>").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Json.parse` takes a string and returns a json object. It needs a valid json input in order to parse the input, this is a string. You can also use the `JSON.stringify` method before call `parse` to ensure passing an input as a string.